# 'list' object has no attribute '_committed' while saving form data

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save the data in my form. Upon checking if the form is valid and trying to save the data, i am receiving **AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'**. I can't understand what the problem is. here is my form.

```
class issueAddForm(forms.Form):
    related_to = forms.ChoiceField(label = "Project")
    title = forms.CharField(label = "Heading")
    description = forms.CharField(label = "Description",widget=forms.Textarea )
    attachments = forms.FileField(label = "Attachment(s)",widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(issueAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['related_to'].choices = [(o.id, o.name) for o in Projects.objects.filter(client=user.id)]
```

views.py

```
def addIssue(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form= issueAddForm(request.user,request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            pr = Projects.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['related_to'])
            ti = form.cleaned_data['title']
            de = form.cleaned_data['description']
            o = issues(related_to=pr,title=ti,description=de,attachments=request.FILES.getlist('attachments'))
            o.save()

    return HttpResponse("added")
```

Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\cap\support\views.py", line 67, in addIssue
    o.save()
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1331, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1275, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1275, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1274, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1225, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "C:\Users\Capcee\Desktop\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 286, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Comment: can you add the complete error traceback?

Comment: Why aren't you using a ModelForm?

Comment: I'm not sure, but replace your line with the following, `o = issues(related_to=pr, title=ti, description=de, attachments=form.cleaned_data['attachments'])`

Comment: Sorry but no one can answer your question without the relevant informations (the full error message and traceback AND the code that generated the error). Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @JPG, Sorry i've added the traceback

Comment: Uhu... You should indeed not pass a list (`request.FILES.getlist()`) as the value for a `FileField`. First because it expects a `File` object (using a `ModelForm` would take care of this BTW), and also because it expects a _single_ file - if you want many attachements for one "issue", you need a related "attachements" model.

Comment: Also your view code should handle GET requests and invalid submissions...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i was trying with a single file. will fix the get requests and invalid submissions. Think i should go for modelform.

Comment: @JPG that fixed the error,with one file. I'll use modelform. Need multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your python version and django version are compatible, faced a similar issue with this configuration -

python version - **3.1**

django version - **3.2.12**

I created a new virtual environment with python **3.8** and it worked like a charm.